# Are this kind of question On topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked these two question on Scfi [1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28809/what-characteristics-does-alpha-beta-wolf-have-in-twilight-series) and [2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28810/how-are-new-werewolves-made). I always prefer M & Tv over Scfi till the On Topic clause doesn't conflict.

So i asked these two question on Scfi because they have these kind of question Previously. But i want know that are this kind of questioned welcomed here or not?

Comment: Blech, Twilight :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as questions like those can be explained properly, I don't see too much of an issue with them, but obviously questions about how series mechanics works is a case by case basis.

Comment: What about these two examples?

Comment: They are fine, but this isn't a license to cross-post them.

Comment: Yes i know and even these kind of question are better handled on Scifi as compare to here. Next time i will post them here.